# How to store permuterms of a token in apache lucene for wildcard queries?

Tags: java, lucene

How to store [permuterms](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/permuterm-indexes-1.html) of a token in apache lucene for wildcard  queries?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any built-in functionality for permuterms in Lucene.

Making use of them would require you to create a custom filter (and an analyzer making use of it) to generate the permuterms at index time, and some sort of function to rotate wildcard queries to effectively use them at query time (a custom query implementation, or perhaps just an extension of or pre-processing step to a queryparser).

This post on the very topic may help with understanding the steps involved: http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/10/lucene-wildcard-query-and-permuterm.html

It's old, and would require considerable changes to work on more recent lucene versions, but the broad strokes should be pretty similar.